# I am trying to apply alert to a dynamic jquery form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to apply alert to a dynamic jquery form which shows error when left empty. It runs without showing any error.

The code prints the form as a part of a slidedown div.

The code for HTML is:

(the div's appear onclick of the previous one)

```
<form method="post" id="frm" name="frm">
    <div id="fnamelogin">
        <label for="firstname">First Name:
            <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Enter First Name" id="fname" />
        </label>
    </div>
    <div id="lnamelogin" style="display: none;">
        <label for="lastname">Last Name:
            <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Enter Last Name" id="lname" />
        </label>
    </div>
    <div style="display: none;" id="idlogin">
        <label for="mailid">E-Mail ID:
            <input type="text" name="usermail" placeholder="Enter Mail Id" id="email" />
        </label>
    </div>
    <div style="display: none;" id="passlogin">
        <label for="password">Password:
            <input type="password" name="userpass" placeholder="Enter your Password" />
        </label>
    </div>
    <div style="display: none;" id="courselogin">
        <label for="course" style="color: white;">Enter Course:
            <br></br>
            <input type="radio" name="usercourse" id="courselogin" value="MBA" />MBA</label>
    </div>
    <div style="display: none;" id="streamlogin">
        <label for="stream">STREAM
            <select name="stream">
                <option>CSE</option>
                <option>IT</option>
                <option>ECE</option>
            </select>
        </label>
    </div>
    <label for="teacherremember">
        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="teacherremember" id="teacherremember" checked="checked" />Remember me</label>
    <p>
        <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Form" />
</form>
```

THE Javascript for checking the empty fields is:

```
$('#frm').submit(function() {

if ($.trim($("#fname").val()) === "" || $.trim($("#lname").val()) === "")
    {       
        alert('you did not fill out one of the fields');   
    }
});
```

Comment: Where is #frm? I'm not seeing it in your HTML

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/be38ankj/1/ this runs fine. I added `return false;` to cancel the form submission if the error occurs.

Comment: How are you adding the javascript to the page? I am thinking the JS is not even compiled into the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go the HTML5 route for form validation. You can use `Required` `Pattern` attributes on your inputs. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9aLp84dt/

The `required` attribute makes so that the form cannot submit without data in the input. The `pattern` makes sure that the data in the input fits your constraints as defined by Regex.

The only gotcha is browser support. Make sure to test your code in all target browsers.